# External Edit pathway on Mac

Tags: texturing, materials, image, uv-image-editor, image-sequence

I'm having issues connecting Photoshop to Blender. My goal is to be able to paint image textures and have them update on my UV maps in real time. All of the tutorials I've seen are on Window Systems. It seems simple enough to just connect the EXE file to blender but I'm not finding that anywhere on my Mac interface. I'm wondering if anyone knows how to connect Photoshop to Blender on a Mac system?

Comment: EXE is app format for PC ... for Mac just navigate to your Photoshop folder and choose **Adobe Photoshop 20??.app** file ... any issue with that?

Comment: Go to preferences>paths>image editor.  Find the file path : /Applications/Photoshop.app.  Then in the image editor window go to image>open externally.  It doesn't work differently on a Mac system.  However, this isn't live painting, for that you need texture paint.